# get string value from registry using p/invoke (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, pinvoke, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to find the COM port assigned to a USB device, through the registry using Silverlight, and have tried the following:

```
dynamic WshShell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
string strRegKeyUSB = @"HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM\\Device\USB_COM";
string strCOMValue = WshShell.RegRead(strRegKeyUSB);
```

This approach usually works 100%, but all Value names under the DEVICEMAP Key is "\Device\XXX"
This causes the the "Path" to not be found, as the "\\" between SERIALCOMM and Device is not seen as valid (Throws Error: "Cannot find File Specified")

This, as far as I can see, only really leaves me with one option - P/Invoke, in Silverlight 5

I am using P/Invoke already for a SerialWrapper Class, to Open, Read, Write the COM Ports, and would like to include only the minimal needed to only read this one Key Value from the Registry - I have tried following some examples I have found, but not being strong in Interop, P/Invoke, etc. I am struggling to find only the portions I need.

If someone could please just give me a basic example, to only accomplish this (I do NOT need to write to the registry, or read QWORDS, or anything else - Only read this string value from only this specific key)

I have tried following the following post ([Marshal.PtrToStructure in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317174/marshal-ptrtostructure-in-silverlight)) and it's answer, in relation to this (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool.enumports), but have not been able to get this working, Most likely form a lack of REALLY understanding ;-)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not quite understand the issue with what you are currently doing.  The double-slash ("\\") would be interpreted literally, because of your use of `@`, so that much is expected.  But why if the actual registry path is `...\DEVICEMAP\Device\XXX` are you instead using `...\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOM\\Device...`?  Why not fix that issue instead of pursuing P/invoke, which will get a lot messier?

Comment: Thank you DonBoitnott,
I Have edited the original post to attach images which will hopefully clarify the problem, You will notice that the actual registry path is "SERIALCOMM\\Device\XXX" - I have tried all variationsof 1,2,3,4,6 slashes, with and without @, appending strings, etc, etc.

Comment: Sorry - I need 10 Rep Points to attach images (But open the DEVICEMAP path in your registry and compare to other paths, and you will soon notice the difference I am referring to.

Comment: Why does `@"HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM\Device\USB_COM` not work? In my registry, I see a key path of `@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` and a value under it of `\Device\Serial0`.  As a value path, that is `@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM\Device\Serial0`.  Are you constructing the path in code?  I just don't understand where the double-slash is coming from.

Comment: Hi Don,
@"HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM\Device\USB_COM" does not work, and still says File not found.
As an Example:

Comment: Hi Don,
@"HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM\Device\USB_COM" does not work, and still says File not found.

As an Example:
@"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Silverlight\" is the final Key with the Value simply "Version" (Right pane in RegEdit), concatenating these to form the path gives us @"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Silverlight\Version"

BUT:
@"HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM\ is the final Key with the Value as "\Device\USB_COM" (Right pane in RegEdit), concatenating these to form the path gives us @"HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM\\Device\USB_COM" as the Value (Right pane) starts with a "\"

Comment: since I can't test that code myself, I'm at a loss.  If you have tried hard-coding that reg path and it didn't work, then there is another problem...it should work.  If you're simply concatenating, are you using somthing like `System.IO.Path.Combine()`, which will automatically fix things like doubled slashes?

Comment: p/invoke is not the solution. Post your image on a file sharing site and I'll edit the question to include it.

Comment: Hi David,
Thank you for your Comment, I certainly would prefer to get away without using p/invoke, I have uploaded the images here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ec3mxrs1d00ar2k/ky0uAvznu-

Comment: Yeah, now I can see your problem! p/invoke might be the solution after all!!

Comment: Thank You David...
Now for the interesting bit.

Comment: What can you do in Silverlight. This is OOB right? You cannot shell out to reg.exe by any change? And you cannot use the .net registry classes right?

Comment: Hi David, as far as I have researched my options are pretty much the "dynamic WshShell" or P/Invoke, Yes OOB, and I currently am using P/Invoke for a SerialWrapper, so using a little more P/Invoke would not make that big a difference, I just do not have the knowledge to make the finer details work, but get 90% there.

Comment: Personally I'd start by writing the code in C++. You just want a function that reads a REG_SZ value. I'd say use C++ because you can be confident that the interop to the Win32 libraries works. Once you have that version working, switch to C#. Develop it on your desktop. Perhaps use pinvoke.net for translations. If you don't use @user2753402 in your replies, I won't get notified. So you just end up talking to yourself.

Comment: Thank You Dave for your assistance thus far, I fortunately do not know even a little of C++, but will keep searching to find the bits I need to get this working in P/Invoke.
Regards, @user2753402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple desktop application that reads a `REG_SZ` value. It's crude and simple. It will read the value that you want. You may have to adapt it to Silverlight. I cannot help you there!

I hope this is useful:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        public const int ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;

        public const uint HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;

        public const int KEY_READ = 0x20019;

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(
            UIntPtr hKey,
            string subKey,
            int ulOptions,
            int samDesired,
            out UIntPtr hkResult
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern int RegCloseKey(
            UIntPtr hKey
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int RegQueryValueEx(
            UIntPtr hKey,
            string lpValueName,
            int lpReserved,
            IntPtr type,
            IntPtr lpData,
            ref int lpcbData
        );
    }

    internal static class RegistryWrapper
    {
        private static void checkErrorCode(int errorCode)
        {
            if (errorCode != NativeMethods.ERROR_SUCCESS)
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
        }

        public static string ReadRegString(UIntPtr rootKey, string subKey, string name)
        {
            UIntPtr hkey;
            checkErrorCode(NativeMethods.RegOpenKeyEx(rootKey, subKey, 0, NativeMethods.KEY_READ, out hkey));
            try
            {
                int cbData = 0;
                checkErrorCode(NativeMethods.RegQueryValueEx(hkey, name, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, ref cbData));
                IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cbData);
                try
                {
                    checkErrorCode(NativeMethods.RegQueryValueEx(hkey, name, 0, IntPtr.Zero, ptr, ref cbData));
                    return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr, cbData / sizeof(char)).TrimEnd('\0');
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                checkErrorCode(NativeMethods.RegCloseKey(hkey));
            }
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(RegistryWrapper.ReadRegString((UIntPtr)NativeMethods.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, @"HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM", @"\Device\Serial0"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

It seems that `AllocHGlobal` and `FreeHGlobal` are not available on Silverlight. You can p/invoke to `LocalAlloc` and `LocalFree` instead. Or you could use `CoTaskMemAlloc` and `CoTaskMemFree`. Here's what the former looks like:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr LocalAlloc(uint uFlags, UIntPtr uBytes);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr hMem);
```

Define `LMEM_FIXED` like this:

```
const uint LMEM_FIXED = 0x0000;
```

Then replace the call to `AllocHGlobal` with this:

```
IntPtr ptr = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cbData);
```

And replace the call to `FreeHGlobal` with this:

```
LocalFree(ptr);
```

Comment: Thank you @David Heffernan,
I have tried implementing this code, and comes very close, but still end up with one of the issues I had in my original post with an error "'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal' does not contain a definition for 'AllocHGlobal'" (Also 'FreeHGlobal'), I know there must be a work around for this, as per suggestions found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317174/marshal-ptrtostructure-in-silverlight (See Bottom of the Answer) - I however cannot figure out how to make this work, as I do not know what the references to "LPTR" & "LocalAlloc" in this post is

Comment: referring to and get "The name 'xxx' does not exist in the current context" for both these references.
I am positive that if I can figure out this workaround I could make this work.
Regards @user2753402

Comment: I take it the accept means that you got the result you wanted. Please to have been able to help!!

Answer (score 0):

A BIG thank you to @Dave Heffernan,
I got this to work FINALLY...

I  Added the following code within the RegistryWrapper class in Dave's Answer:

```
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr LocalAlloc(uint uFlags, int size);

        internal static IntPtr AllocHGlobal(int size)
        {
            uint LPTR = (uint)0x0040;
            IntPtr hGlobal = LocalAlloc(LPTR, size);
            if (hGlobal == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new OutOfMemoryException("Unmanaged memory was not allocated.");
            }
            return hGlobal;
        }
```

This works around the limitation of Marshal.AllocHGlobal not being available in Silverlight.
I then also just changed the reference to Marshal.AllocHGlobal to the local AllocHGlobal method above.

Comment: PS: I still now need to look at Marshal.FreeHGlobal, as this is also not available (To free the memory allocated in Unmanaged code, after use)